# Google Cloud Bucket - Upload File - 403 Forbidden Android SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: java, android, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

So following the GCSSignedURLExample.java example from here

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Construct-the-String

I tried the code in eclipse. simple .java file program from my macbook.
And it worked great. I can see the text file getting created when i sign in to console.developer.google.com and browse bucket content.

But the same piece of code i tried executing from Android. I am getting 403
error.

So this below code works fine when runs from a .java program from mac. but when executed in android it gives 403.

Any help will be appreciated. I can add more piece of code if required.

```
        key = loadKeyFromPkcs12(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret".toCharArray());

        System.out.println("======= PUT File =========");
        String put_url = this.getSigningURL("PUT");

        URL url = new URL(put_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
        out.write("Lorem ipsum");
        out.close();

        System.out.println("PUT Request URL: " + put_url);
        System.out.println("PUT Response code: " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
        renderResponse(httpCon.getInputStream());
```

EDIT

Ok so debugging 403 more i found out its a SignatureDoesNotMatch

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
    The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
    Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>

<StringToSign>PUT
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    1456322965
    /my-bucket/234/somerandomfile.txt
</StringToSign>
```

I am still unable to figure this out. Here is the signing code. Which is same what i am doing on eclipse java code(The working one)

```
private String getSigningURL(String verb) throws Exception {
    String url_signature = this.signString(verb + "\n\n\n" + expiration + "\n" + "/" + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + OBJECT_NAME  );
    String signed_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + OBJECT_NAME +
            "?GoogleAccessId=" + SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL +
            "&Expires=" + expiration +
            "&Signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(url_signature, "UTF-8");
    return signed_url;
}

private PrivateKey loadKeyFromPkcs12(String filename, char[] password) throws Exception {

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    ks.load(getAssets().open(filename), password);
    return (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("privatekey", password);
}

private String signString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
    if (key == null)
        throw new Exception("Private Key not initalized");
    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signer.initSign(key);
    signer.update(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] rawSignature = signer.sign();
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawSignature, false), "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved it. 
No straight document led me here.

Its the number of \n you put after the verb that was causing issues for me.

check this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Construct-the-String

```
String url_signature = this.signString(verb + "\n\n" 
+ "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
+ "\n" + expiration + "\n" + "/" + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + OBJECT_NAME  );
```